# wp_link_pages: display current page number only if has multiple page breaks?

Tags: functions, wp-link-pages

I'm trying to build a function to display the current chapter (page) within the single.php file ONLY if there's more than one chapter (page break).

This function will output the chapter # within the page header under the title. Then I will customize and use the wp_link_pages at the bottom for the chapter pagination.

Currently, my function doesn't work, it return nothing and if I remove the the IF statement if ( $multipage ) {} it return "Chapter 0".

I need advice on this one.

```
/**
* Get current chapter number
*/
if ( ! function_exists( 'sbwp_get_current_chapter' ) ) {

    function sbwp_get_current_chapter() {

        global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more;

        if ( $multipage ) {
            echo '<p class="page-link accent">';
            echo esc_html(( '' . __( "Chapter ", "sbwp" ) . '' . $page ));
            echo '</p>';
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How's your loop? Does it contain a call to `the_post()` ? Does it work on the default theme?

Comment: @birgire The function is called outside of the loop. Here is the complete single.php on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VK01HSUp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$multipage` is constructed inside the `setup_postdata()` method of `WP_Query`.
It's called when you run `the_post()`. So just as @s_ha_dum explained, you have to make a loop around it:

You can try this:

```
if( have_posts() )
{ 
    the_post();                      // Make a call to setup_postdata().
    echo sbwp_get_current_chapter(); // Display the current chapter.
    rewind_posts();                  // Rewind back.
}
```

before your main loop, where you must remember to rewind back.

Answer (score 2):

`$multipage` is an ["inside the Loop" variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Inside_the_Loop_variables). I did not track down exactly where and how it is set but given that information alone the obvious solution is to [put your code inside a Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), which is good practice anyway as a number of things depend upon that Loop. Something like:

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts() {
      the_post();
      $sbwp_story_thumbnail = "";
      // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I have resolved this issue. My function needed to placed inside the loop as you said.